# angularjs -date input with ng-model in miliseconds

Tags: angularjs, date, input, angularjs-ng-model

I have a number which represents the time in miliseconds since 1970 eg.

1388664300000

with:

```
{{ day.date | date: "dd.MM.yyyy" }}
```

it will render **07.05.2015** ! So far so good. Now I like to insert the same data into my input field:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="day.DUTY">
```

to let the user adjust the date.

Nothing is displayed because the input field requires an date object ! 
I have created a filter to change my number to date:

```
var DateFilter = function() {
        return function(data){

        date = new Date(data);
        return date;
      }
    }
```

But I can't figure it out how to combine this with my input field. Maybe this isn't the right approach ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Try day.date = new Date(day.date)?

Comment: This won't work ! Syntax error

Comment: You need to make a directive for manipulating the data and represent in differently.

Comment: By the way angular has the built in filter for the date. check in here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: You should be able to find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517883/how-to-bind-view-date-to-model-milliseconds-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to bind View Date to model milliseconds with Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517883/how-to-bind-view-date-to-model-milliseconds-with-angularjs). 
As it explained; You can use the following, to change the data format dynamically during the binding:

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);  
ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am nearly done but there is one problem which I don't understand. Here is my fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/altsel/5u4c9b7j/) ! If you open this in chrome for example the input field with the type of date stays empty ! Regarding this official angular doc example: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) The date is shown correctly ! Where is my mistake ? In my eyes I am doing the same with `code`return new Date(text);`code`

Comment: The reason is that you are not using the Chrome date formats. You can check the correct format from here http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime-def       Then you can use input type="date" without any problem.   If you want to use this format just put the input field from type="date" instead of type="text" and it will get solved.

Comment: use new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]; // "2014-09-30" to create a date in correct format